# SharePoint Online - Library column not being picked up as crawled property

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, crawled-property, search-schema

I'm new to SharePoint Online.  I have created an Office 365 account and am trying to setup a simple test of search on a document library in a site in my site collection.

I've added documents to a doc. Library and created a custom column called MTest (Single line of text).

When I search, I'm getting back results from the document library.  I am now trying to map the Crawled Property to a Managed property, but I can't find the crawled property in the Search Schema.  I've searched from the Site Setting -> Search Schema.  I've also search the Search Shema at the Site Collection level.

I've gone into the Document Library Setttings and clicked Reindex Document Library and waited a couple of hours now.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: That is really weird. You have added some docs to the library and set a value in the MTest field?

Comment: Yes.  I've added text to every field in that column.  I've gone to Site Settings -> Site Features and made sure to Activate SharePoint Server Standard Features...which includes Search

Comment: Just to make sure that the crawler works perhaps you could try this: go to site settings , add a MTest2 site column , add that to the library from Library setting, and set some value in those fields, reindex the library and wait.

Comment: Kasper.... I added the site column (a managed property) and waited.  Still no crawled property.  I was under the impression that SharePoint Online would pick up a column within an hour but according to this post (2013, but the comments are recent) it can take days before you see your crawled property.  I redid everything to be sure and clicked reindex on the doc library.  I'll let you know.  Here is the article: https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/10/waiting-for-search-crawl-in-office-365.html